# Avoiding statusbar to expand without hiding it

Tags: android, lockscreen, keyguard

I'd like to add in my app a keyguard like the one used in Go locker / MX player.

Both the apps allow you to see the statusbar but you cannot pull it down. I already found some tricks to draw over the statusbar but this is not what I'm looking for...I'd like the statusbar to be always visible but not accessible.

I know there is a system permission that allow to make the statusbar not expandable but, of course, there is no way to include this permission in a not-system app. Do you know any other way to make the statusbar not expandable?

Thank you,
Vinc